# Using Mahout in Java Application

Tags: java, hadoop, mahout

i want to write a Java Application (for University) which uses Latent Drichlet Allocation (LDA). The only Framework i found which offers LDA was Mahout.
I have quite some expierience in Java programming, even though i would not consider myself a Java Pro (I am coming from PHP).
The application will not be used in a distributed computing context, so the mahout / hadoop way might be a way over the top, but if i am right it should at least work.

My Problem:
The Mahout wiki etc. does not really help me, in fact i do not understand a single word. I dont want to use mahout in that "terminal way". I just want to load the classes into my application and kind of do something like that:

documents = obj.load(Documents);
mahout.doLDA(documents);

(I know it will not be that easy, but i am sure you know what i mean).

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Mahout's libraries could be used in *local mode*, without full Hadoop cluster.  You can look to [examples from "Mahout in Action" book](https://github.com/tdunning/MiA) to see how this could be done.